# Show total number of rows in SQLite table

Tags: javascript, sql, database, sqlite

I am building a local database with this :

```
var db = openDatabase('LIST','1.0','database', 2*1024*1024);

db.transaction(function (tx) {
  tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS entry (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, first TEXT, last TEXT, email TEXT, phone TEXT, contest TEXT, added_on DATETIME)');
});

db.transaction(function(tx){
  tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO entry (first, last, email, phone, contest, added_on) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)',
  [vFirst, vLast, vEmail, vPhone, vContest, addedOn]);
});
```

How would I populate a div with count of total rows in the database? I guess I would use something like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM entry` .. but I am unclear on how to write this or print the output on the page.

If I was using local storage I see I could do something as simple as `var length = window.localStorage.length;` but I can not figure out how to do something similar with SQL.

Comment: Just to be clear, do you want all rows from the *database* or from the `entry` table? Also, what JavaScript framework/library are you using?

Comment: I am using jquery and yes just from the entry table.. but now I am only working with one database.. I updated my question to include the creation of the db too..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to count all rows from `entry` table, then `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM entry`
If you want to know count of rows in database, then `UNION` queries from different tables and sum using `SUM()`

**EDIT:**

```
db.transaction(function(tx) {
   tx.executeSql("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM entry", [],
      function(tx, result) {
         //console.log(result.rows);
         console.log(result.rows.item(0)["count(*)"]);

         // do the html stuff to push this value to div
      },
      function(tx, error){
         // error occured
      }
   );
});
```

Comment: thanks my problem though is figuring out to actually display that count.  Can you please show me how this would be written

Comment: not a javascript guy, but maybe this code helps, totally untested!!! Edited my answer

Comment: hmmm thanks .. i see in the console though it is just returning length of 1 > SQLResultSetRowList length: 1 but I have over 30 test entries...